# Re-render a rendered component with async Fetch called by Callback button Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, conditional-rendering

I'm new in react and I'm creating an application that has the purpose of performing calculations to make cryptocurrencies strategies, the thing is that, I already have the programmed API but I need the data to be updated through a callback that re-renders data obtained from an Asynchronous API fetch just like the Binance page https://www.binance.com/es-LA/convert where it shows you a price and when you press the update button it renders with the updated data

I still don't get along with hooks and I even thought to using Jquery to use that function, in which case it would be with ajax but I want to do everything in react so as not to include more libraries

my json is like that

```
{
      "response": "1",
      "remesaspatria": {
        "LTCUSD": "60.990000000000002",
        "LTCEUR": "60.178832999999997"
      },
      "Binance_LTCUSD": {
        "mins": 5,
        "price": "61.03271805"
      },
      "patriaexchange": {
        "BSPTR": "421,99",
        "PTRBTC": "415,46134749",
        "PTRLTC": "1,13874534",
        "USDPTR": "53,73",
        "USDBTC": "22.324,64",
        "USDLTC": "61,19",
        "BSUSD": "7,98"
      },
      "monitorweb": {
        "BCV": "7,984",
        "ENPARALELOV": "8,10",
        "DOLARTODAY": "8,16",
        "MONITORWEB": "8,17"
      }
    }
```

my app.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFetch } from './fetchData'

const PillContents = (n) => {
  const data ='https://api.mysite.site/?site=crypto&apikey=mykey' // API URL
  const { loading, apiData } = useFetch(data)
  //const [apiV, apiVUP] = useState('')

  const [valuesC, setValuesC] = useState({ refB: 'hidden' })

  const handleCalc = () => {
    setValuesC({ ...valuesC, refB: '' })
  }
  const handleRef = () => {
    ... here is going to be a update vars function  ...
  }
  return (
    <MDBRow>
      <MDBCol md='6' className='mb-4'>
        <form>
          <MDBRow className='mb-4'>
              <MDBBtn className='mb-4' type='button' id='calc' onClick={handleCalc}>
                CALCULAR
              </MDBBtn>
              <MDBTooltip tag='span' wrapperClass='d-inline-block' placement='top' title='Actualizar precios'>
                <MDBBtn className={`mb-4 ${valuesC.refB}`} type='button' style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} id='refc'
                  onClick={handleRef}>
                  ACTUALIZAR
              </MDBBtn>
            </MDBTooltip>
          </MDBRow>
        </form>
      </MDBCol>
    </MDBRow>
  )
}
```

fetchdata.js file

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    // Async request
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const apiData = await response.json()
      setApiData(apiData)
      setLoading(false)
    }
    getData()
  }, [url])
  return { loading, apiData }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not English.

Comment: ok, i going to replain my question in english, sorry for any incovenient caused it

Comment: FYI aside from translating to English, you can also repost to es.stackoverflow.com (Spanish-specific). Aside from that: please also add clarification in your question - what is the specific issue you're having? You included a lot of code, and it's unclear what your specific issue is. Please include all relevant details.

Comment: basically i need to a 'update button' that going to update just rendered data. this button call to fetch data function and returned updated data render it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `mutate` function and return it in your custom hook (just like SWR library).

##### `app.js`

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useFetch } from './fetchData'

const PillContents = (n) => {
  const data ='https://api.mysite.site/?site=crypto&apikey=mykey' // API URL
  const { loading, apiData, mutate } = useFetch(data)
  //const [apiV, apiVUP] = useState('')

  const [valuesC, setValuesC] = useState({ refB: 'hidden' })

  const handleCalc = () => {
    setValuesC({ ...valuesC, refB: '' })
  }
  const handleRef = () => {
    mutate();
  }
  return (
    <MDBRow>
      <MDBCol md='6' className='mb-4'>
        <form>
          <MDBRow className='mb-4'>
              <MDBBtn className='mb-4' type='button' id='calc' onClick={handleCalc}>
                CALCULAR
              </MDBBtn>
              <MDBTooltip tag='span' wrapperClass='d-inline-block' placement='top' title='Actualizar precios'>
                <MDBBtn className={`mb-4 ${valuesC.refB}`} type='button' style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} id='refc'
                  onClick={handleRef}>
                  ACTUALIZAR
              </MDBBtn>
            </MDBTooltip>
          </MDBRow>
        </form>
      </MDBCol>
    </MDBRow>
  )
}
```

##### `fetchdata.js`

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

  const mutate = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const apiData = await response.json()
    setApiData(apiData)
    setLoading(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, [url])

  return { loading, apiData, mutate }
}
```

I just renamed your `getData` function and moved it to useFetch scope.

> note: you can also take advantage of `useCallback` hook to prevent useless re-renders.